# Check out lastest development version

Tags: bazaar

What is the `bzr` equivalent of

```
cd ..
rm -fr widelands
git clone url/to/widelands.git
```

?

After searching for hours yesterday, how to get rid of local changes, I rage quit and did:

```
$ cd ..
$ rm -fr widelands
$ LANG=C bzr branch lp:widelands # LANG because of the well known not yet fixed bug
Branched 8986 revisions.                                                                                                                                                                                                              
$ cd widelands
$ LANG=C bzr checkout
bzr: ERROR: A control directory already exists: "file:///[...]/widelands/".
```

???

```
$ LANG=C bzr remove-tree .
```

bzr: ERROR: Working tree "[...]/widelands/" has uncommitted changes (See bzr status).

????????????

```
 $ bzr status
 removed:
   [list of thousands of files]
```

?????????????????????????????????

```
$ ls -lA
total 2
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 2048 Feb 21 15:43 .bzr
```

According to this page https://wl.widelands.org/wiki/Building%20Widelands/, the steps to get the current development version of widelands is:

```
bzr branch lp:widelands
cd widelands
bzr checkout
[further steps to compile etc]
```

And that's basicly, what I tried above.

/edit: I now successfully tried `LANG=C bzr revert --no-backup` which didn't help me in the old repository before I rage quit, but the question still applies.

Comment: The "bzr checkout" instruction on that page looks incorrect. There's no need to run that. The "bzr branch" command creates a checkout by default.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're trying to do is remove the existing clone and create a new one, then the equivalent in bzr is:

```
$ cd ..
$ rm -fr widelands
$ bzr branch lp:widelands widelands
```

If you're trying to get rid of pending changes in the current control directory (i.e. `git reset --hard`),  then `bzr revert` is what you're after.

Comment: ```bzr branch lp:widelands widelands``` is basicly what I tried, just the last argument was omitted, but it branched into that dir anyways. I'll test around in a few days about this again maybe with a smaller repo. Oh, and the ```bzr revert``` didn't work in the old repo, that's why I just deleted it in the first place, the changes were not worth any conflict resolving but I got in a state, where I didn't know how to just get to dev head and no google search helped either. All I found just assumed you want to keep your changes.